# How do I handle Product Flavors in a React Native Android app?

Tags: android, react-native, android-flavors, android-flavordimension

My React Native app has 3 versions: App1, App2, App3.  Each of these has a dev and prod version.

I've set these up in android/app/build.gradle as follows:

```
flavorDimensions "client", "backend"
    productFlavors {
        app1 {
            applicationId="com.app1name"
            dimension "client"
        }
        app2 {
            applicationId="com.app2name"
            dimension "client"
        }
        app3 {
            applicationId="com.app3name"
            dimension "client"
        }
        dev {
            dimension "backend"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "backend"
        }
    }
}
```

I've then set up android/app/src folders like this:

```
src
-- main
   -- assets
   -- java
      -- com
         -- app1name
            MainActivity.java
            MainApplication.java  
    -- res
    AndroidManifest.xml
```

But I'm not sure where to put the other app folders, and whatever I try doesn't seem to work.  I've tried:

```
src
-- app2name
   -- assets
   -- java
      -- com
         MainActivity.java
         MainApplication.java  
    -- res
    AndroidManifest.xml
```

(and the same for app3)

and I've tried:

```
src
-- main
   -- assets
   -- java
      -- com
         -- app2name
            -- assets
            -- java
            -- com
               MainActivity.java
               MainApplication.java  
            -- res
            AndroidManifest.xml  
    -- res
    AndroidManifest.xml
```

I've made sure that each AndroidManifest.xml/MainActivity.java/MainApplication.java has the correct package name at the top.

However, I get the following error when I try to run app1name (it builds and installs ok):

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.app2name/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.app2name/com.app2name.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

So it looks as though it's trying to start app1, but for some reason is also looking for the main activity in app2, and I can't see why it's doing that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please tell what's the command you run to build the app?

Comment: react-native run-android --variant=app1nameDebug

Comment: To handle different application id, you need to add the application id in your command as well, react-native run-android --variant=app1nameDebug --appId=com.app1name

Answer (score 6):

To handle multiple productFlavours, you need to either add application id suffix, or the complete application id in your run command.

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=app1nameDebug --appId=com.app1name
```

Alternatively if you have appSuffixId mentioned in your productFlavours, then

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=app1nameDebug --appIdSuffix=dev
```

Answer (score 1):

How I added **React Native version: 0.73+**

1. Install `react-native-config`.
2. Create your `.env` file (depending upon you). In my case, I have created three env files first `.env.dev`, second `.env.production`, and third `.env.staging`.
3. Under `your_project_name/android/app/build.gradle` add below line

   ```
   apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + 
   "/dotenv.gradle"

   project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
     dev:".env.dev",
     prod:".env.production",
     staging:".env.staging",
   ]
   ```

just like this

[image]

4. Add your Flavors

   ```
   buildTypes {
   debug {
       signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
   }
   release {
       // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
       // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
       signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
       minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
   }
    }
   // below code 
   flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {  
       development {  // change development according to your build name
         dimension 'default'
         applicationIdSuffix ".development"   // here also
       }
    }
   ```
5. Like this

[image]

6. In `package.json` file

   ```
   "androidDevelopment": "ENVFILE=.env.production react-native run-android --mode=developmentDebug --appIdSuffix=development"
   ```

Like this[image]

7. My `.env` file

[image]