# How to integrate react-native assets with Flavor/Target?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Is there a way to build several versions of the same application. The only information that differs is the name of the application, the package and a folder with auduo files embedded in the app?
I use react-native.

Build 8 apks with the same code but different name, package name and audio assets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I handle Product Flavors in a React Native Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70462567/how-do-i-handle-product-flavors-in-a-react-native-android-app)

Comment: I saw this post, it is interesting but does not indicate how to integrate react-native assets. Thank you for answer.